# how to remove duplicated character in string using php?

Tags: php, string

I'am doing a project which is cleaning text with php.
say that i have string like this :

```php
$string = 'Life is like. . . . . . a box of chocolate. . . . . '; //each dot separated by space
```

How can i get the output like

```php
$string ='Life is like a box of chocolate';
```

Comment: Use `str_replace()` and replace dot+space with nothing.

Comment: Your question title is confusing. What should be the output of `Life is like. . . . . . a box of chocolate. . . . ., but I don't like chocolates, lol` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated character"?

Comment: Do you want to remove only the dots?

Comment: Sorry if my question confusing. thank for your comment @vivek_23

Comment: yes,i mean the duplicated character is the dots. @NicoHaase

Comment: yes, i want to remove them @Valentino

Comment: Please add all further explanation to the question itself. Don't scatter this in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`preg_replace`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string = 'Life is like. . . . . . a box of chocolate. . . . . ';
echo preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your expected result is just to strip the dots and surrounding spaces, you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), but to get your expected result you need a bit more complex regex:

```
echo preg_replace(array("/(?<!\w) *\. */", "/(?<=\w)\. */"), array("", " "), $string);
```

Here I use an array of two regex to match two different cases:

1. a dot followed and preceded by 0 or more spaces, all preceded by a character which is not a letter or a digit (`\w` in regex means a letter or a digit, and this is a negative lookbehind). This is substituted by an empty string.
2. a dot followed by 0 or more spaces, and preceded by a letter or a digit. This is substituted by a space.

2 is to match and remove the dot in `'like. '` but leave a single space after the word.

This gives your expected result: `'Life is like a box of chocolate'`

You can learn more on regex (short for regular expression) looking for tutorials on the web.

Answer (score -1):

isn't it an easy str_replace()?

```
str_replace(". ", "", $text);
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? Try to use `test. second` as an input string